# How to limit the scope of a shared variable so that it can only be access in one function?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Shared _twolettercountryCodeDict As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
Private Function twolettercountrycode() As String


    If _twolettercountryCodeDict Is Nothing Then
        _twolettercountryCodeDict = New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"ty", "turkey"}, {"py", "pakinmay"}, {"ra", "romania"}, {"vm", "vietnam"}, {"bl", "brazil"}, {"et", "egypt"}, {"ka", "korea"}}
        Dim listOfCountries = fileToCol(COUNTRYCODESFileName)

        For Each var In listOfCountries
            Dim ar = var.Split({"*"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
            _twolettercountryCodeDict.Add(LCase(ar(1)), UCase(ar(0)))
        Next
    End If

    Return _twolettercountryCodeDict(Me.twoletter.ToLower)
End Function
```

Here, I am using     `Private Shared _twolettercountryCodeDict As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)`

That's because I want to share that _twolettercountryCodeDict for the whole program. I am basically implementing lazy loading. I do not want part of the code that read a text file and populate country codes are done again and again.

The thing is if I declare it as Private Shared, other methods on the same class can access that variable too. Which is not much of a problem but say I want to avoid it.

If I declare the variable as static inside the function then the twolettercountryCodeDict won't be shared.

So I am in a dilemma. What's the solution?

Let's just say that twolettercountrycode requires a private member, so it can't be a shared function. But I want _twolettercountryCodeDict to be shared and accessible only from twolettercountrycode. Can I do so?

Comment: Declare a read only Private Shared property that returns the value of a Private variable that you set in the function.

Comment: That's the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do precisely what you asked for, but it solves the requirement of only allowing the resource loading to be done once.  You could achieve the same thing by using a [Shared Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711965(v=vs.71).aspx) on a class that's solely for loading your resource.

You may also want to use a [ReadOnlyDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx) ([implementation](/questions/678379/is-there-a-read-only-generic-dictionary-available-in-net)) so that your dictionary can't be modified by callers.

```
Friend Shared ReadOnly Property twolettercountrycode As Generic.Dictionary
    Get
        Static _twolettercountryCodeDict As Generic.Dictionary = Nothing
        If _twolettercountryCodeDict Is Nothing Then
            _twolettercountryCodeDict = New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"ty", "turkey"}, {"py", "pakinmay"}, {"ra", "romania"}, {"vm", "vietnam"}, {"bl", "brazil"}, {"et", "egypt"}, {"ka", "korea"}}
            Dim listOfCountries = fileToCol(COUNTRYCODESFileName)

            For Each var In listOfCountries
                Dim ar = var.Split({"*"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
                _twolettercountryCodeDict.Add(LCase(ar(1)), UCase(ar(0)))
            Next
        End If
        return _twolettercountryCodeDict
    End Get
End Property
```